# Spring: How to inject a Supplier<String> function as constructor parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've coded this class:

```
@Component
public class AuditFactory {

    private Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier;

    public AuditFactory(Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier) {
        this.auditIdSupplier = auditIdSupplier;
    }
}
```

It's used as a dependency of a `@Service` class:

```
@Service
public class AuditService {

    private AuditFactory auditFactory;

    public AuditService(AuditFactory auditFactory) {

        this.auditFactory = auditFactory;
    }
}
```

How could I tell to Spring that injects a `Supplier<String>` when `AuditFactory` is injected?

**EDIT**

```
@Bean
public Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier(FrontOfficeProperties frontOfficeProperties) {
    return () -> String.join(
        "-",
        frontOfficeProperties.getCpdId(),
        frontOfficeProperties.getRedisAuditKeyPrefix(),
        UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    );
}
```

where `FrontOfficeProperties` is an `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class.

Comment: Define a Bean for Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier as Spring is unaware of what to inject.

Comment: I've edited post. Do you think this bean will work?

Comment: you are on right path, just missing `@Autowired` annotation on both the properties `private Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier;` and `private AuditFactory auditFactory;`

Comment: Hi @Jordi i have posted one solution can you please check and do let me know it's useful for you if yes please upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below approach might help you to fix your issue.
also can you please share Supplier class as well.

```
@Component
public class AuditFactory {

    private Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier;

    public AuditFactory(Supplier<String> auditIdSupplier) {
        this.auditIdSupplier = auditIdSupplier;
    }
}



@Service
public class AuditService {

    private AuditFactory auditFactory;

    public AuditService(AuditFactory auditFactory) {
        this.auditFactory = auditFactory;
    }
}
```